# How to select * but exclude <body>? Or set <body> to default style?

Tags: css, css-selectors, userstyles

Browsers usually set different default styles for elements. Users can also override the defaults using  [custom stylesheets](https://www.google.com/search?q=user%20stylesheet).

I often override these default styles using my own styles, e.g.:

```
* {padding:0; margin:0; }
```

However, I wish to respect the default stylesheet for certain element attributes, e.g. the `<body>`'s default padding and margin. I tried:

```
*    { padding:0;       margin:0;       }
body { padding:default; margin:default; }
```

But it doesn't work. Neither does `initial`.

Is there a way to solve this problem by selecting all elements but excluding `<body>`?

Comment: This is a little silly.. for one thing, it's a good idea to zero out the `margin` on `html, body`. Instead, you should add `margin` onto your container `div`, or whatever. If you really want to do it, then customize a CSS Reset.

Comment: Probably even easier, sticking with what you have: `*{padding:0;margin:0;} body{margin:10px}` - that way, you don't have to use the inefficent `*` (at least, *not again*), and the `body` margin is definitely consistent between browsers.

Comment: @thirtydot but not consistent between user defined stylesheets which was what i meant when i said *default*

Comment: @Pent: Almost *no users* care about the precise `body` margins. Those that *do care* would be using `!important` to make sure their custom `margin`s stick, if it's *that important* to them (they'd have to, because every other website in the world sets `body { margin: 0 }`, or whatever number). See the CSS spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules. Why do you care so much about preserving the *default* margins?

Comment: @thirtydot i'm merely looking for a solution to be able to do so.

Comment: @Pent: And that's fine, and you have your answer. But I think your logic is faulty somewhere, because I can't see how what you asked for is *actually useful*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to solve this problem by selecting all elements but excluding `<body>`?

Since everything that is displayed in the viewport consists of `<html>`, `<body>` and `<body>`'s contents by default, you can just select `html`, and all of `body`'s descendants:

```
html, body * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

`default` doesn't work because there is no such keyword. `initial` doesn't work because the initial margins are 0. It is not possible to reset a property to its browser-given default value after you have changed it using CSS.

Comment: You can [display the `title`](http://jsfiddle.net/twT4F/) with `head, title { display: block; }` :)

Comment: @Pent Read it here a few years back.

Comment: @Boltclock i'd not even tolerate a penalty of 0.1 seconds, but i really don't get why it will be slow, since the css is first read, then the html, at the time when `*` is read, isn't it true that there aren't much elements even if the entire page is supposedly packed with elements?

Comment: @Pent: It's slow because the browser needs to calculate styles for **every element** in the page.

Comment: @Boltclock isn't it such that it is first calculated at the `</style>` ending tag and cached in `computed styles`, and used for each element that it comes across later?

Comment: @Pent: The browser calculates and displays stuff as the page gets downloaded, so it's all in real-time. That's one of the effects of cascading.

Comment: @BoltClock, Hmm, I doubt this is true anymore for modern browsers. There are ways to optimize this easily.

Comment: @Pacerier: Yeah, time flies - I would trust that too. I see you've rewritten your question so it's time I updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
html, head, head *, body * { }
```

Comment: @alex: Margins and padding aren't inherited.

Answer (score 2):

`<html>` and all descendants of `<body>`:

```
html, body * {padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: shucks man they should really have an xpath like way to specify exceptions

Comment: Actually, it does. You can use `:not(body)` as the selector, but old browsers don't support many CSS3 selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `body *` selector.

```
body *{padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set them first to 0, then override the wanted values afterwards. You'd be better off using a CSS Reset though, but if you reall want to use the asterisk, this method will work.

```
   * {
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
   }

   body, html {
     padding: 10px;
   }
```

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: i mean i knew i could do it this way of course, but its not guaranteed 10px you see. its user defined, so how do i know what's the user-defined padding/margin for body?

Comment: Are you referring to the browser specific stylesheets? Why would you need to keep them the default of the browsers? Set something to make the page look the same for each browser. :)

If you really want to investigate the defaults, you could use inspect tools and check computed styles of your body\html tags before you apply any special styling.

Comment: yep definitely i listed the "default" in the question